# Backbone events hash vs jquery event declaration

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

If I declare my events in a Backbone view's 'events' hash, like so:

```
    events: {
        'mouseenter #socialMediaContainer': 'showSocialMediaLinks',
        'mouseleave #socialMediaContainer': 'hideSocialMediaLinks',
        'mouseenter #socialMediaContainer .links li': 'emphasizeSocialMediaLink',
        'mouseleave #socialMediaContainer .links li': 'resetSocialMediaLink',
    },

    // Never gets fired
    showSocialMediaLinks: function (e) {
        alert('mouse enter SM');
    },

    // Never gets fired
    hideSocialMediaLinks: function (e) {
        alert('mouse leave SM');
    },

    // Works fine
    emphasizeSocialMediaLink: function (e) {
        alert('emphasize SM');
    },

    // Works fine
    resetSocialMediaLink: function (e) {
        alert('reset SM');
    },
```

the first two events fail to fire, but the last 2 work fine.  The only difference I can see is that the selector specifies a sub-element (eg: `#socialMediaContainer .links li`, but I'm not sure why that would make any difference.

The relevant HTML source is as follows:

```
    <div id="socialMediaContainer">
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/images/socialmedia/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/images/socialmedia/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/images/socialmedia/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/images/socialmedia/googleplus.png" alt="Google+" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/images/socialmedia/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="shareTab">
            <div>Share</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I add an `initialize()` method to this view, and set up the event handlers there, they work fine:

```
    initialize: function() {
        $('#socialMediaContainer').on('mouseenter', this.showSocialMediaLinks);
        // etc...
    },
```

but ideally I'd like to be able to just use the events hash for consistency.  Any idea why those first 2 events don't seem to get bound, but the second 2 do?  For what it's worth, I also tried using `this.showSocialMediaLinks` as the value in the events hash, as well as the string `'showSocialMediaLinks'`.

I think I've included all relevant information above, please let me know if you need anything else for a diagnosis.  Thanks.

Comment: Is `#socialMediaContainer` you view element? If it is, could you try `'mouseenter': 'showSocialMediaLinks'` ?

Comment: Yeah, this was the issue.  I didn't understand that selectors were relative to `el`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you initialized your view by attaching it to the `#socialMediaContainer` div. Example:

```
var myView = new MyView({
   el: $('#socialMediaContainer')
});
```

By doing this, all your events will be relative to the `#socialMediaContainer` div.

To fix this, you can do this:

```
events: {
    'mouseenter': 'showSocialMediaLinks',
    'mouseleave': 'hideSocialMediaLinks',
    'mouseenter .links li': 'emphasizeSocialMediaLink',
    'mouseleave .links li': 'resetSocialMediaLink',
},
```

As for the following jQuery event:

```
$('#socialMediaContainer').on('mouseenter', this.showSocialMediaLinks);
```

This works because it isn't relative to the `#socialMediaContainer` div. It is essentially global.

The weird part for me is that the last two events worked when you did this:

```
events: {
    'mouseenter #socialMediaContainer .links li': 'emphasizeSocialMediaLink',
    'mouseleave #socialMediaContainer .links li': 'resetSocialMediaLink',
},
```

I'm honestly not sure why that worked. But I tested it out and worked for me also. Could be a bug?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.  I wasn't entirely clear on the purpose of `el`

Comment: Like you say, it's odd that it resolves those final 2 selectors properly.  I don't know if it's specific to IDs - maybe because it's unambiguous, the selector code goes "well, i'm already working with this element, so i'll ignore that"